# Start with a specific page in Ag-grid 9.1.0

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid table 9.1.0 with lazy paging

I need to be able to boot through a specific page that I want.

I mean, for example. Just load show page 2 (values from 10 to 20)

I manually set the value of startRow and endRow to 10 and 20 respectively.

```
var dataSource = {
    rowCount: function () {
      return rowCountBk;
    },
    getRows: function (params) {
      ///my implant
      params.startRow = 10;
      params.endRow = 20;
    }
  };
```

But paging keeps pulling me up on page 1.

How can I force to start with the page that I want

Comment: What do you mean 9.1.0? 19.1.0?!

Comment: It is in production and we can not change versions of anything.